# Pivoting a Pandas Dataframe containing strings - add the columns in the first time one only and other wise it add values in any column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

good morning all 
i have many files with the following format but with different values in **measure** column

```
subject_id     hour    measure      value

2               1      heart rate    40
4               3      SPO2          high
```

i want to reshape data using pivot table , so that i use the following code

```
    df1 = df.pivot_table(index=["subject_id" ,"hour"], columns='measure', values=['value'], aggfunc='first')
    df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
    df1 = df1.reset_index()
    df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()
    print (df1)
 with open('patients.csv', 'a',newline='') as f: 
    df1.to_csv(f, header=True)
```

it works good and give me the following file

```
subject_id    hour    heart rate    spo2
2              1        40          
4              3                    high
```

but the problem when i want to concatenate another file to the same  file `patients.csv`
let say the new file is

```
subject_id     hour        measure      value

    5               4      resp          50
    6               4      urine         200
```

i use the same code mentioned above to add the values and the new columns

```
 df1 = df.pivot_table(index=["subject_id" ,"hour"], columns='measure', values=['value'], aggfunc='first')
        df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel()
        df1 = df1.reset_index()
        df1.columns=df1.columns.tolist()
        print (df1)
     with open('patients.csv', 'a',newline='') as f: 
        df1.to_csv(f, header=True)
```

hence it didnt add the new measure as a new columns , it only add the new patients and add the values to the old columns as follows

```
subject_id         hour    heart rate       spo2
    2              1        40          
    4              3                        high
    5              4        50
    6              4                        200
```

so that the output file is incorrect and i want it to be as follows

```
 subject_id         hour    heart rate       spo2     resp    urine
    2              1        40          
    4              3                        high        
    5              4                                   50
    6              4                                            200
```

how can i solve this problem
any help will be appreciated

Comment: How do you concat the second file to the first? Please add the code in the question, and not as a comment.

Comment: ok , done ,, you can check now

Comment: I think you just copied the former code by mistake... (I'll delete this comment when fixed)

Comment: it is the same code , but it run with every file to concatenate the results to the final file at the first time we can use only save  **pivot_table.to_csv('\\ path) **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate the data in `python`, and not just add it to the file every time. Once you have the data from the first file in "patients.csv", read it with:

```
original_data = pd.read_csv("patients.csv")
```

And after you create `df1` as you did in your code, concat them with:

```
full_data = pd.concat([original_data, df1], sort=False)
```

And then you can save it with:

```
full_data.to_csv("patients.csv", index=False) # Always better option to work with csv files than "with open... as..."
```